# jenkins pipeline project error:Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, jenkins, jar, pipeline

have a error "Error: Unable to access jarfile ",
when my pipeline project execut a shell script ->"java -jar xxx.jar"

Error: Unable to access jarfile /var/lib/jenkins/*************.jar

I try chmod 777 ***.jar
and setting my jenkins boot user and group ->>root:root

Comment: I think your script running on wrong path, before running the script try to run ‘pwd’ to get your exact path.